# git workflow: how to properly switch task between two interdependent branches?

Tags: git, github

I have feature A and Feature B, each being developed on a separate branch, A and B respectively.

When I have A done, I run it to test it. I would like to immediately start working on B while A is testing. However, I am going to be actively changing files (mostly additions) while A is running. At various points in time, files A relies on may not compile correctly because I am actively working on them.

Furthermore, as A is testing, I am going to want to fix little things here and there with A. I don't want to have to stash on B, go to A, make the change, then come back to B for every little change.

Apart from getting a different test machine to pull a specific commit hash of the repo and test it while I continue to work on it elsewhere, what solutions exist for this problem? My method has been to copy the entire git directory so I have another space to temporarily work in while the original directory temporarily acts as a testing location.

Comment: When you want to switch between branches with uncommitted code, you use a stash. Even when only altering small bits of code. And why not just wait until your tests have run, *then* switch?

Comment: You could rebase B on top of A after every fix you make on A. Thus commit on B, switch on A, fix the bug, get back on B, rebase B on top of A.

Comment: @obsidianAge, yes after letting this bake a bit, I'm finding the best compromise is to let all the test run, then fix things in batch (as much as possible) - or videotape the run to watch and fix later. That ideal doesn't always match reality as a lot of the failures occur from me half-observing A run as it's difficult to write good test catches for end to end robotics. Of course the unit test failures and others I can wait until the end to fix though.

Comment: *copy the entire git directory so I have another space to temporarily work in* It's called a **worktree** and it's a solution. I use a worktree for any long-lived branch, thus I don't need to stash files before switching branches because I don't switch branches (but I have to sync git repositories as there are many).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need separate work-areas in which to run tests (that the tests would otherwise step on each other), your current method—using an extra copy of the repository—is good.  The only way to make it better, with an opinion punctuation mark around the word "better", would be to use `git worktree add` to share the underlying repository while having two separate work-trees.

(`git worktree` is new in Git 2.5, with various fixes over time; I'd recommend having at least 2.6 before using it.)